# design pattern for caching nested (or child) objects

Tags: object, caching

I have an class as below. I have a concept of caching in my application. 
At some time, suppose one Profile has 25 ABC objects , and the data is stored in DB.

Now , while using my application, i may or may not use all 25 ABC objects. How do i design my classes to cache the code. One approach can be that i fetch all 25 ABC objects and cache the Profile object. (But that would have performance hit)

Usually , you cache the objects as required , but how do i do it. I cannot cache ABC objects separately because the other fields in Profile class are required along with these.

```
class Profile
{
String name;
String country;   AND 5 more fields

List<ABC> obj;
}
```